# How can I use the replace function to change the headers in a .txt file?

Tags: python, replace, text-files

I have a text file with weather data in comma demilited format. This data has headers that're for their corresponding data. But these headers are too long, i.e. too many characters. So I want to replace them with shorter names. How can I use the replace function in python to replace them?

```
longlist = [Date, HighTemperatureF, LowTemperatureF]
shortlist = [D, HT, LT]
```

So, I want to replace longlist with shortlist. This is what I have so far.

```
for i in range(len(longlist)):
    longlist.replace(longlist[i],shortlist[i])
```

But I don't think this would work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are your headers always at the top of the file? Are they always the same length? If so, you my be able to just do some slicing and string addition instead.

Comment: No, I append several different data together, so I have like 15 different headers in the .txt file.

Comment: Just use `longlist = shortlist[:]` to copy the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to replace text in the text file. I just give you the code to show you the general concept because I don't know how your actual text file looks like.

Please note that the elements in `shortlist` must be enclosed in quotes like this `'D'`.

```
x = open('yourtextfile/text.txt', 'r')
longlist = [line.split(',') for line in x.readlines()]
shortlist = ['D', 'HT', 'LT']
longlist = shortlist[:]
print longlist
```

Output:

```
['D', 'HT', 'LT']
```

If you want to write it back to the file you can do this:

```
x = open('C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/test3.txt', 'w')
for i in longlist:
    x.write("%s, " % i)
x.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the value to the header:

```
with open('weather_data') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
lines[0] = 'D, HT, LT'
```

now, the header should be 'D, HT, LT', if you want to save it:

```
with open('processed_weather_data', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```